# What does the keyword parameter ax=ax mean when plotting a pivot table?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, methods

I am struggling with finding information about keyword arguments regarding the plotting method of a DataFrame.

Example: I have the variable births_by_date which is a pivot table. In a textbook, I have the following lines of code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
births_by_date.plot(ax=ax)
```

Because I wanted to know more about the keyword argument ax I checked the docstring for births_by_date.plot in my Jupyter Notebook. But I couldn't find information about what keyword parameters are possible in this method...

The only information I have found in the docstring is:

`**kwds` : keywords
    Options to pass to matplotlib plotting method

The online documentation refers only to specific methods, the "general" plot method doesn't answer my question: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot

It seems to me that a general plot method does not exist anymore in matplotlib 0.25.3, is this correct? 
How can I get information about keyword arguments, that are allowed with a DataFrame plot method (or a pivot table plot method in my case)? Where can I especially find information about the keyword argument ax?

Comment: plt.subplots() returns fig, ax. ax stands for Axis and the class can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes). With ax, you can control various parameters (xticks, yticks, label, etc. ) of the Axis (X-Y grid).

Comment: The older link to the documentation has a bit more information about some of the keywords: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html

Comment: To add, with simple single plots it's sometimes unnecessary to specify an axis object. But once things get more complicated, like with subplots, the additional control is useful. For instance, see what happens when you do `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4), ncols=2); births_by_date.plot(ax=ax[1])`

Comment: Thanks @ALollz. I wonder, why in the newest documentation they provide only information about specific plot methods. I cannot find anything in the new documentation about the keyword ax...but you are right the older version has more infos. What if someone does not know that? The specific methods do not contain information about ax as keyword argument.